# Getting Lat,Lng from the DB and set it to JS function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

Here is my problem I strated to use google maps and the thing is:

on my website I have RadComoboBox with location that I populate from the DB, and on right hand side

asp panel and on it I'm displaying google map. The issue is I want that the user select location

From the RCB and it will show on the map.(the all idea is to take the lat,lon and send it to the simple code of google and show it on the map)

My idea is save all the location into ArrayList and serialized it and saving it to HiddenField after

that using it in js and desirailed it.

but the problem that nothing really happens!!!

here is my Code:

***Back Code VB.NET***************

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Public Class LocationInfo
    Private m_LocationID As Integer = 0
    Private m_LocationName As String = Nothing
    Private m_LocationLat As String = Nothing
    Private m_LocationLng As String = Nothing

#Region "LocationInfo Properties"
    Public Property LocationID() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_LocationID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_LocationID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LocationName() As String
        Get
            Return m_LocationName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_LocationName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LocationLat() As String
        Get
            Return m_LocationLat
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_LocationLat = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LocationLng() As String
        Get
            Return m_LocationLng
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_LocationLng = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

End Class


 Public Sub GetLocationInfo()
        Dim LocationList As New List(Of LocationInfo)
        Dim dba As New DBAccess
        Dim ds As DataSet = dba.GetUserLocationsByID(m_User.UserID)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
            Dim locationInfo As New LocationInfo
            locationInfo.LocationName = dr("LocationName")
            locationInfo.LocationLat = dr("Lat")
            locationInfo.LocationLng = dr("lng")
            locationInfo.LocationID = dr("LocationID")
            LocationList.Add(locationInfo)
        Next
        Dim oSerilzer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim sJson As String = oSerilzer.Serialize(LocationList)
        hfLocationList.Value = sJson.ToString()


    End Sub


*****************************aspx code*****************************


     function getValueFromList() {
            var jsonString = document.getElementById('hfLocationList').value;
            var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        }

        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052055, -118.460490)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);





                                <td>Locations:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfLocationList" Value="0"/>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbLocations" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadComboBox>

<div id="map-canvas">

          <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="150px">

          </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('hfLocationList').value
```

do this

```
document.getElementById('<%= hfLocationList.ClientID %>').value
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can also set the ClientIdMode property of the asp.net control to Static

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfLocationList" Value="0" ClientIdMode="Static" />
```